# What to pass in for dispatch_queue_attr_t

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

I've been reading through various tutorials on Grand Central Dispatch.  As the examples tend to use null for the second creation parameter, i.e.:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create(com.something.myqueue, NULL)
```

I'm struggling to understand what the second argument is used for.  Is it generally just null, as per the examples e.g. in http://jeffreysambells.com/2013/03/01/asynchronous-operations-in-ios-with-grand-central-dispatch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument specifies what type of queue you want: serial or concurrent.

If you ask for a serial queue, then blocks submitted to the queue will be executed in the order they were submitted, one at a time.

If you ask for a concurrent queue, then blocks may (or may not!) execute at the same time on different threads within the queue.

You'll see in the definition that `NULL` means serial.  Here's the definition from queue.h:

```
/*!
 * @typedef dispatch_queue_attr_t
 *
 * @abstract
 * Attribute for dispatch queues.
 */
DISPATCH_DECL(dispatch_queue_attr);

/*!
 * @const DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL
 * @discussion A dispatch queue that invokes blocks serially in FIFO order.
 */
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL NULL

/*!
 * @const DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT
 * @discussion A dispatch queue that may invoke blocks concurrently and supports
 * barrier blocks submitted with the dispatch barrier API.
 */
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT \
        DISPATCH_GLOBAL_OBJECT(dispatch_queue_attr_t, \
        _dispatch_queue_attr_concurrent)
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_3)
DISPATCH_EXPORT
struct dispatch_queue_attr_s _dispatch_queue_attr_concurrent;
```

So what you want to pass depends heavily on what you're doing and whether or not what you're doing is parallelizable.

Comment: So if I wanted to make it parallel it would be dispatch_queue_create(com.something.myqueue, dispatch_queue_attr_concurrent)?  Is that correct?  I'm struggling to work out what to pass in for a parallel queue.

Comment: Yes.  Concurrent is a general synonym for parallel.  Consider though that GCD will manage the queue based on system resources, etc, so passing concurrent doesn't guarantee parallelism.  [This](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-25-gcd-practicum.html) might be some good reading to help understand how GCD works.